# Cursor get row id returns 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to retrive the row ids for rows in my table but i get zero for all rows. This is the essentially what I'm doing:

```
long getIdForPosition(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    long _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyTable.COLUMN_ID)); // The value for COLUMN_ID is "_id"
    cursor.close();
    return _id
}
```

This returns zero for all rows. The cursor is valid and it moves to a valid position

Comment: Did you include the COLUMN_ID in the query?

Comment: Yup... I'm using `null` as the projection so all columns should be returned.

Comment: What version of Android are you developing for? And can we see your Table creation statement?

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong. Was caused by my not fully understanding how the _id field works. I didn't create it with the autoincrement keyword so that column was not being populated. Thanks for the hint, made me look at the create statement closer.